# Polymorphic tricky situation

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

This is the code in Java language:

```
class A{
   A() {  print();   }
   void print() { System.out.println("A"); }
}
class B extends A{
   int i =   Math.round(3.5f);
   public static void main(String[] args){
      A a = new B();
      a.print();
   }
   void print() { System.out.println(i); }
}
```

It prints **0, 4**.
But why does from the super class A within constructor you invoke subclass print method? I see that the print method is overridden, but in fact the 'print' method has been called from the superclass...
That is the drill in order to prepare for Java certification.
Best regards

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: I thought the output might be A, 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't invoke `print` in the *constructur* of `A`. This is where it prints `0`, because the instance of `B` apparently isn't fully initialized yet, and the value of `B.i` apparently still is `0`.

The **implicit constructor** of `B` is:

```
public B() {
   super(); // invokes B.print!
   this.i = Math.round(3.5f);
}
```

As you can see, print gets executed before `i` is initialized. Yet, you have overridden `print`, the old print is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

Object type(not the reference type) determines which overriden method is used at runtime/

```
A a = new B();
a.print();// this would always call B's print() in case of overriden methods
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing is the reference that you use to access an object and another thing the actual type of the object. This is basic [subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism).

Your object is of type B, because that's what you created (i.e. new B()). Now, you happen to access your object through a reference of type A, which is possible because B *is an* A (B extends A).

When you invoke the method *print* through your reference, the runtime type system knows that even when the reference is of type A, the actual object the reference points to is of type B, and therefore, it looks for the method *print* in B first. That is the one being invoked then and that explains the output that you see.

Your *print* method is what they call a [virtual method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method). This means that it is the runtime system which determines which implementation of all implementations of the method will be invoked only based on the nature of the target object of the invocation at runtime.

Now, with this clear, your overriden implementation in B is what is being called. *The overriden implementation does not automatically trigger the implmentation in the parent class*. This is somewhat different from the behaviors in constructors (which cannot be inherited but can be chained).

So, this basically means that if from your overriden method you want to access the behavior of the parent you have to ask your super class to do it (i.e. super.print())

As such, if you were dealing with constructors, like in the following case

```
class A {
   public A() { System.out.println("A"); }
}

class B extends A{
  public B() { System.out.println("B"); }
}
```

If you create an instance of B, you should see an output of A B.Because constructors are automatically chained, and the constructor in B invokes the constructor in A.

But in the case of virtual methods, you need *explicitly* chain the execution (if that's what you want) something like this:

```
class A {
   public A() { System.out.println("A"); }
   //virtual method
   public void print(){ System.out.println("A"); }
}

class B extends {
  public B() { System.out.println("B"); }
   //virtual method overriden
   @Override
   public void print(){ 
      super.print(); //invokes A.print
      System.out.println("B"); 
   }
}
```

...in order to see the output A B.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a method on an object, it always uses the implementation of the object's actual type, even if it's called from within a superclass.